# How to define time column in in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame" "seied_log":

```
seied_log
Out[155]: 
       0
0   5.264761
1   5.719328
2   6.420809
3   6.129704
...
```

What I run is ARIMA model:

```
model = ARIMA(seied_log, order=(2, 1, 0))
```

Hovewer I receive the following mistake:

```
ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

What I need, is to define a "date" column. These are yearly observations. How can I define a column with date starting from 1978?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your index is 0 through n_obs-1, then simply

```
from datetime import datetime
seied_log["date"] = seied_log.index.map(lambda idx: datetime(year=1978+idx, month=1, day=1)
```